# F# set to list with set.fold

Tags: list, f#, set

I'm programming in F# and I'm trying to make a set into a list by using Set.fold.

What I've done so far:

```
let list sa = Set.fold (fun se sa -> sa) [];;
```

but it doesn't seem to make the set into a list, rather it makes a
set of lists into a list.

What change can I make to my code so it won't make a set of lists into a list, but a set into a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let toList s = Set.fold (fun l se -> se::l) [] s
```

1st argument of `fold` is the function taking two parameters: accumulator of type that should be returned from `fold` (`list` in your case), and a single element of collection `fold` applies to (element of `Set` in your case). This function should return the type same of accumulator passed as the 1st parameter (`list` in your case). So the function should add current element of the set to list accumulator.

2nd parameter of `fold` is the initial accumulator state (empty `list` in your case).

3rd parameter of `fold` in your case is the Set you want to transform to `list`

Answer (score 1):

Using Set.fold you will receive the items in reverse order:

```
let list sa =  sa |> Set.fold (fun se sacc -> sacc::se) [] |> List.rev
```

Or, use Set.foldBack:

```
let list2 sa =  Set.foldBack (fun se sacc -> se::sacc) sa []
```

Example:

```
let list sa =  sa |> Set.fold (fun se sacc -> sacc::se) [] |> List.rev
let list2 sa =  Set.foldBack (fun se sacc -> se::sacc) sa []

let set = [1 ; 12; 6 ;8 ; 4] |> Set.ofList

set |> printfn "%A"

list set |> printfn "%A"
list2 set |> printfn "%A"
```

Print:

```
set [1; 4; 6; 8; 12]
[1; 4; 6; 8; 12]
[1; 4; 6; 8; 12]
```

Link:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/xwLMIp

P.S. There is a standard function [Set.toList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353484.aspx)

Comment: [Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353619.aspx) collection does not assume any specific ordering of constituents, so fiddling with ordering of derived `List` collection doesn't add value.